# React Components Not Rendering on Devices Until Window Size is Changed

Tags: css, reactjs

I followed the JS mastery tutorial to create my portfolio website using react.js. I modified the project card into the following

```
const ProjectCard = ({
  index,
  name,
  category,
  description,
  topics,
  libraries,
  image,
  source_code_link,
  link_labels,
  links,
}) => {
  return (
    <motion.div variants={fadeIn("up", "spring", index * 0.1, 0.75)} className='flex sm:flex-row flex-col w-full p-4'>
      <Tilt
        options={{
          max: 20,
          scale: 1,
          speed: 450,
        }}
        className='bg-tertiary p-10 rounded-2xl w-full shadow-card flex sm:flex-row flex-col'
      >
        <div className='relative w-full sm:w-1/2 h-[300px] '>
          <img
            src={image}
            alt='project_image'
            className='w-full h-full object-fill rounded-2xl'
          />

          <div className='absolute inset-0 flex justify-end m-3 card-img_hover'>
            <div
              onClick={() => window.open(source_code_link, "_blank")}
              className='black-gradient w-10 h-10 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer'
            >
              <img
                src={github}
                alt='source code'
                className='w-1/2 h-1/2 object-contain'
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='mt-5 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-5 sm:w-1/2'>
          <h3 className='text-white font-bold text-[24px]'>{name}</h3>
          <p className='mt-2 text-secondary text-[14px]'>{category}</p>
          <p className='mt-2 text-secondary text-[14px]'>{description}</p>
          <p className='mt-2 text-secondary text-[14px]'>Topics : {topics}</p>
          <p className='mt-2 text-secondary text-[14px]'>{`${libraries}`}</p>
          <p className='mt-2'>
            Links :{" "}
            <a href={links.l1} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
              {link_labels.label1}
            </a>
            &nbsp; {" "}
            <a href={links.l2} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
              {link_labels.label2}
            </a>
          </p>
          
        </div>
      </Tilt>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

My website is up on github at `https://kabirthakur.github.io/portfolio/`.
The GitHub link is `https://github.com/kabirthakur/portfolio`
The text part is there and I can somehow select the information but the card itself is not being rendered. If i change the window size of the browser the project card will randomly appear. Once it appears there are no problems. On smaller devices like ipad however the project card will sometimes render if I completely zoom out the page.

I tried using different values for flex but still having difficulty rendering the project card on different browsers.

Comment: I tried your code on Chrome but it looks fine to me? And I didn't change my window size or something.

Comment: It was working fine on a few devices and the project cards were showing up but it wasn't working on any mobile devices. I figured the problem was the animation so I have temporarily removed the motion.div tags and it's working fine on all devices